# Integrating Spring & JDBC into JSF2 login page

Tags: spring, jsf, jdbc, authentication, integration

I've used a properly running [example project](http://code.google.com/p/springsecurity/) ([documentation](http://ocpsoft.com/java/acegi-spring-security-jsf-login-page/)) to create a simple JSF login page working with Spring Security on Tomcat 7 using Eclipse. The above example stores usernames, passwords and roles in applicationContext-security.xml in the following format:

```
<authentication-provider>
  <password-encoder hash="md5" />
  <user-service>
    <user   name="rod"
            password="a564de63c2d0da68cf47586ee05984d7"
            authorities="ROLE_SUPERVISOR, ROLE_USER, ROLE_TELLER" />
    <user   name="peter"
            password="22b5c9accc6e1ba628cedc63a72d57f8"
            authorities="ROLE_USER" />
  </user-service>
</authentication-provider>
```

I am trying to modify it so that I can use authentication database through JDBC. After making a simple modification, I am no longer able to access my project on the server (404) due to an error (Eclipse does not provide details, or maybe I don't know where to look). Could you please give me some suggestions on what might be going wrong? Thanks.

Below is a complete copy of my updated applicationContext-security.xml:

```
 <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                         http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.1.xsd">

    <global-method-security
        secured-annotations="enabled">
    </global-method-security>

    <http
        auto-config="true"
        access-denied-page="/accessDenied.jsp">

        <intercept-url
            pattern="/faces/protected**"
            access="ROLE_SUPERVISOR,ROLE_USER,ROLE_TELLER" />
        <intercept-url
            pattern="/**"
            access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />

        <form-login
            login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
            login-page="/faces/login.jsf"
            default-target-url="/"
            authentication-failure-url="/faces/login.jsf" />
        <logout
            logout-url="/logout*"
            logout-success-url="/" />

    </http>

    <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
    </authentication-provider>

<beans:bean id="userDetailsService" class="org.springframework.security.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl">
  <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
  <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql:///mysampledb"/>
  <beans:property name="username" value="root"/>
  <beans:property name="password" value="root"/>
</beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved! I had to remove this:

```
<beans:bean id="userDetailsService" class="org.springframework.security.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl">
  <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</beans:bean>
```

As it created more than one instance of userDetailsService, which caused the error.

Comment: <beans:bean id="userDetailsService" class="org.springframework.security.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl">
  <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</beans:bean>

Comment: Please checkout the buttons on top of message editor and the message formatting rules on the right hand column while inside the message editor.